# Extending Material UI theme via Module Augmentation not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I'm trying to add an "input" property to the background field within palette and then augment the Theme to account for types, like so:

```
export const lightTheme = createTheme(commonTheme, {
  palette: {
    mode: 'light',
    background: {
     default: '#FFFFFF',
     input: '#0000BB',
      ...
}
```

```
declare module '@mui/material/styles' {
  interface Theme {
    background: {
      input: React.CSSProperties['color'];
    };
  }

  interface ThemeOptions {
    background: {
      input: React.CSSProperties['color'];
    };
  }
}
```

However, when I try to access background via `color: theme.palette.background.input`, i get an error:

`Property 'input' does not exist on type 'TypeBackground'.`

Why is augmentation not adding the type to the background property?

To add, I also tried this which didn't change anything:

```
declare module "@mui/material/styles/createPalette" {
  interface CommonColors {
    background: {
      input: React.CSSProperties['color'];
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to extend the type TypeBackground as shown below:

```
declare module '@mui/material/styles' {
   interface TypeBackground {
        input: string;
    }
}
```

and then configure a new value for `background.input`

```
const theme = createTheme({
  ....
  palette: {
    background: {
      input: "#f60"
    }
  }
 ...
});
```

Finally, we can use it like this:

```
<Box sx={{ bgcolor: "background.input", width: 100, height: 100 }} />
```

[The demo link](https://codesandbox.io/s/customstyles-demo-material-ui-forked-htjhrw?file=/demo.tsx)

Comment: Thanks, this works. It is a shame that the [official docs on adding custom color tokens](https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/palette/#typescript-2) does not work for `background`. Or am I missing it? Could not find it in the offical dos.